# How can i display all column of a database table using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a database table `users` containing columns `id(int),name(string),department(string),password(string)`.I am storing table contents in an `arrayList` object in a `servlet (display.java)` and then forwarding it to a `jsp` page(`home1.jsp`). But i am unable to display all tables using that jsp page.Id contents is not showing and the columns of table has been shifted 1 unit right. i.e not under correct header.

```
@WebServlet("/Display3")

public class Display3 extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Display3() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection conn = null;

        Statement st;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection
               ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=Tpg@1234");

            ArrayList al=null;
            ArrayList userList =new ArrayList();
            String query = "select id,name,department,password from users";

            st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);


            while(rs.next())
            {
                al  = new ArrayList();
                al.add(rs.getInt(1));
                al.add(rs.getString(2));
                al.add(rs.getString(3));
                al.add(rs.getString(4));
                userList.add(al);
            }

            request.setAttribute("userList",userList);

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/home1.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

the jsp code is here

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*;" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script language ="javascript">
            function editData(id){
            }
            function deleteData(id){
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <table align="center">
        </table>
        <br>

        <table border='1' width='300' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=6 align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td><td>Department</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>                       
        <%
            List Li = new ArrayList();
            Iterator  lr;
            if(request.getAttribute("userList")!=null && request.getAttribute("userList")!="")
            {
                List userList =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("userList");
                Iterator itr = userList.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    Li = (ArrayList)itr.next();
                    lr = Li.iterator();
                    Integer id = (Integer)lr.next();
        %>
        <tr>
        <%  
                    while(lr.hasNext())
                    {
        %>
            <td><%=lr.next()%></td>
        <%
                    }
        %>
            <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="edit" onclick="editData(<%=id%>);" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteData(<%=id%>);"></td>
        </tr>
        <%
                }
            }
        %>
    }
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: userList is an ArrayList, so is this valid `request.getAttribute("userList")!=""` ?

Comment: Also why not use an existing Framework like struts, stripes of Spring MVC?  This code is JSP is so last century

Comment: please no more scriptlet

Comment: i'm a newbie in java. I don't know struts and Springs.

Comment: Do not write `itr.next()` twicein a while loop for same ArrayList, this could be a reason for `the columns of table has been shifted 1 unit right.`

Comment: What does `<td><%=lr.next()%></td>` show? What it prints? When you cast the id in `Integer id = (Integer)lr.next();` you are doing it also for all the strings. There are a lot of improvements that you can do (using a [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) statement for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cast `Integer id = (Integer)lr.next();` you are shifting the position of the iterator by one position.

The method [Iterator#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) automatically moves your iterator by one position. When in your while you call

```
<td><%=lr.next()%></td>
```

you start from 2nd position, leaving out your id.

I strongly suggest you to read about [generics for your array list](http://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-tutorial-example-class-interface-methods-wildcards-and-much-more), [object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and above all [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

The most important is ORM, you should create a [POJO java class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) to contain a row of your table:

```
public class User {

    int id;
    String name;
    String departament;
    String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDepartament() {
        return departament;
    }
    public void setDepartament(String departament) {
        this.departament = departament;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }   
}
```

Then you can iterate your result set and add a new user for each row:

```
//...
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
//...
while(rs.next())
    {
        user  = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        user.setName(rs.getString(2));
        user.setDepartament(rs.getString(3));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString(4));
        users.add(user);
    }
```

now you can iterate over the list using

```
for(User user: users){
    //Whatever...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iterator Once you have called the `.next()` the pointer is moved to next element. Since you have called the id using `Integer id = (Integer)lr.next();`. The pointer will move to the next value in the list. So if you are trying to print the id in   `<td><%=lr.next()%></td>` it wont. Instead it will print the name.

instead you can change your jsp with the below one

```
Integer id = (Integer)lr.next();
        %>
        <tr>
<td><%=id%></td>
        <%  
        while(lr.hasNext())
        {

            %>
            <td><%=lr.next()%></td>

            <%

        }
```